# Theorem 6.17 in Baby Rudin (Riemann-Stieltjes Integral)

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 6.17: Assume $\alpha$ increases monotonically and $\alpha'\in\mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$. Let $f$ be a bounded real function on [a, b]. Then $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ iff $f\alpha'\in\mathscr{R}$, in which case $\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\alpha'(x) dx$.

My question: Rudin never showed why $\overline{\int}_a^b f(x) \alpha^\prime(x) \,dx$ exists in the first place. Now, if $\alpha'$ is bounded on $[a, b]$, then it is not hard to show $f(x)\alpha'(x)$ is also bounded on $[a, b]$, which then implies that $infU(P, f\alpha')$ indeed exists; but such assumption is not given in the theorem statement. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin does infact mention that $\alpha'$ is Riemann integrable, which implies that it is bounded. Recall that the definition of Riemann integrability given by Rudin applies to bounded functions only.

Comment: I appreciate the help - that was precisely my conjecture; but I failed to prove that Riemann integrable implies boundedness.

Comment: " I failed to prove that Riemann integrable implies boundedness." you really need to get into the habit of _knowing_ definitions!

Comment: Great advice David - I must.